# Subsets using Binomial coefficients and the Binomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics

I've been trying this question but with no luck. Could someone please help with the following question? Thanks!

Prove that if $n \geq 2$, we can find a collection $S$ of at least $\frac{2^n}{n}$ subsets of $[n]$ such that no set in $S$ contains another one.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you share us your attempt? Perhaps we can help from there. Do you know Sperner's theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Show that if two subsets of $[n]$ have the same cardinality, neither of them is contained in the other. For $k\in[n]$ let $s_k$ be the number of subsets of $[n]$ of cardinality $k$. The mean value of the numbers $s_1,\ldots,s_n$ is $\frac{2^n-1}n$. Use the fact that $[n]$ has only one subset of cardinality $n$ to show that there is some $k\in[n]$ such that $s_k>\frac{2^n-1}n$. Then show that because $\binom{n}k$ is an integer, $s_k\ge\frac{2^n}n$.